# Insert variable in a filename or objectname

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way for me to put `[objects objectNamed:@"level"[insert i]"start"];`

This is the only way I can do it for now, but I want to replace it the numbers with i.

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *objects = [theMap objectGroupNamed:@"level1_oj"];
NSMutableDictionary *start1;
if(i ==0)
{
    start1 = [objects objectNamed:@"level1start"];
}
if(i ==1)
{
    start1 = [objects objectNamed:@"level2start"];
}

CGFloat x = [[start1 valueForKey:@"x"]intValue];
CGFloat y = [[start1 valueForKey:@"y"]intValue];

levelstart[i]=ccp(((x/2)-i*480),y/2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
[objects objectNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%dstart", i]];
```

You need to use `stringWithFormat:` for such cases. `%d` or `%i` can be used to represent integers and `%@` can be used to insert strings. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a).

Comment: Thanks @user2121776. Not a problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [NSString Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)

You want to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

For more details on the format have a look at [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Comment: +1, Since both answers were posted at same time and yours is also correct.

Comment: Thx! Sometimes I prefer to provide a little less information to encourage people to read through the documentation.